# Where to add the UTF-8 extension in the HTML page?

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, html, character-encoding

I need to add the charset="utf-8" at the end of the script tags to get the translation to another language done.

I don know where all I should add the tags. Any rules are followed. Please let me know where to add the charset. Do i need to add at the end of "ApplicationLoader.js" or only after the jquery plugins. Any suggestion please.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My Web App</title>   

<link href="css/jquery/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.depends.js" charset="utf-8"></script>             
<script type="text/javascript" src="myemployeelist.js" ></script>
```

---

**Update:**

I will make it more easy for you to understand my situation in details and am not a more stuff guy am a newbie under training now.As far as I understood I will explain my problems to you.

1. I created a webapplication project in Eclipse, in which I created a class
   for JDBC connection to MySQL.
2. I have a class in serverside which gets the users profile value from my webapp 
   textbox and saves in DB.
3. I am using jQuery plugin for doing translation from English to Arabic.
4. I have an HTML page in which as stated in the above part of question I have the 
   tags in which I added the charset="utf-8" to specify unicode.
5. I am using dwr to get the values in js and send it to server side.
6. I changed my computer input language to Arabic and my Mozilla firefox locale to
   Arabic.

I am able to enter the English values in mysql and I am able to retrieve it but when I 
 enter a Arabic value it's not getting saved. The JDBC error is

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xD8\xB3\xD9\x84\xD8\xA8...'
```

I dont know how to configure my server Jetty 6 `LANG` variable to `utf-8`. Any suggestion please. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a [`Content-Type`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) header is present in the HTTP response headers, then this will override the meta headers. Very often, this header is already by default supplied by the webserver and more than often the charset is absent (which would assume client's default charset which is often ISO-8859-1). In other words, the meta headers are generally only interpreted whenever the resources are opened locally (not by HTTP). Big chance that this is the reason that your meta headers apparently didn't work when served over HTTP.

You can use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) or [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com) to determine the HTTP response headers. Below is a Firebug screen:

[image]

You can configure the general setting for HTTP response headers at webserver level. You can also configure it on a request basis at programming language level. Since it's unclear what webserver / programming language you're using, I can't go in detail about how to configure it accordingly.

---

**Update**: as per the problem symptoms, which is the following typical MySQL exception:

> ```
> java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xD8\xB3\xD9\x84\xD8\xA8...'
> ```

The byte sequence `D8 B3 D9 84 D8 A8` is a valid UTF-8 sequence which represents those characters `سلب` ([U+0633](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0633/index.htm), [U+0644](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0644/index.htm) and [U+0628](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0628/index.htm)). So the HTTP part is fine. You mentioned that you were using Jetty 6 as servletcontainer. The later builds of Jetty 6 already support UTF-8 out of the box.

However, the problem is in the DB part. This exception indicates that the charset the DB/table is been instructed to use doesn't support this byte sequence. This can happen when the DB/table isn't been instructed to use UTF-8.

To fix the DB part, issue those MySQL commands:

```
ALTER DATABASE db_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

And for future DB/tables, use `CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci` in `CREATE` statement as well.

Comment: @Balu I am using mysql database, java in server side, jdbc for connection.

Comment: @leo: I wasn't talking about the DB server, but about the webserver. But since you're talking about Java/JDBC, I'll assume that you're using a JSP/Servlet webcontainer. If that is indeed true, then go through the solutions section of [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html).

Comment: I would hope that adding a UTF-8 BOM would cause the files to be served `charset=utf-8`.

Comment: @Balu no am not using JSP and servlet. My webserver in the sense i am using Jetty6. Is it ok now

Comment: @Balu Thanks for that nice article.I am going through that and I will come back with my doubts.

Comment: @leo: Jetty **is** a JSP/Servlet container. But you sounds like as if you're only serving static HTML. Is this true? Anyway, you can configure it in Jetty startup script by setting the `LANG` environment variable to `en_US.UTF-8`. Note that there were some bugs in some subversions of Jetty6. Ensure that you're using latest Jetty6.

Comment: @Balu No am not using static HTML. How to configure it in jetty startup. I want to configure in eclipse? As far now I added charset="utf-8" in my meta tag of the HTMl page.In jdbc url I added ?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8. In mysql i added the charset to utf-8 and collation to utf8_general_ci. But still it not works.

Comment: So, you're using JSP? Please describe the symptoms in detail. What kind of characters are you seeing in which file (and what are you expecting)? Is the the correct charset is present in response header of the particular file? The meta tag is irrelevant in this particular case. It's ignored by the browser when the content is served over HTTP, as explained in the answer.

Comment: @balu Please see my update.I made this to expalin my problem clearly.

Comment: @balu super. thanks a lot for your guidance its working fantastic

Comment: @balu also i have another doubt please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255436/my-language-translation-does-not-work-in-google-chrome-and-ie. this is next part of my learning thing. thanks a lot balu sir.thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

It is usually enough to declare the main document's encoding once, either through a `content-type` header (See @BalusC's answer for an in-depth explanation) or, if that is not available, the Meta tag.

If you use the Meta tag, make sure it is in the first line of the `head` section.

There should be no need to specify the character set explicitly for the script files.

Of course, all the content you deal with needs to be UTF-8 encoded as well for this to work. It's not enough to just slap the content-type meta tag in front. (But you are probably aware of that.)

Comment: -1 for stating that meta tag is enough, +1 for stating that the file itself should be encoded using the same charset.

Answer (score 2):

In this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[path]/myscript.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Why would he need to do that if the parent page is already UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: thanks.is it needed add the utf-8 at the end of script tag? or meta tag itself is enough?

Comment: You are right Pekka, He already have the UTF-8 encoded, but his question was, where to put the char encoding in the javascript file?
And I answered this.. but you're right, he doesn't need it.

Comment: I s enough the meta tag. But if you want to specify on Script.. this is the way. To be honest, you don't need it.