# How to set the locale for mysql?

Tags: language-agnostic, unicode, mysql, utf-8

I need to do language translation from English to arabic.

So i need to set the locale for mysql database table. I am creating a table in mysql like

```
  CREATE TABLE userinfo (
  id int(45) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_sex int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  user_date_of_birth date DEFAULT NULL,
  user_city varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  user_hometown varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_basic_info_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (user_id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
  );
```

I need to add the locale for the mysql table above for arabic. I referred [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/locale-support.html) but I am not able to implement it. How to to do this. Please explain me. I need guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my answer on [your related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245386/where-to-add-the-utf-8-extension-in-the-html-page), you need to issue the following commands on an existing DB/table to it to accept UTF-8:

```
ALTER DATABASE db_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

When creating new DB/tables, use `CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci` in `CREATE` statement as well.

Comment: thank you very much. i am checking it right now. But my confidence made me to accept your answer. I know it will work exactly.
my doubt is if i alter the database alone is it enough or I need to alter all the tables also. I have many tables related to translation.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable  CHARSET=cp1256 COLLATE=cp1256_general_ci;
```

Comment: Thanks. i want to convert it to utf-8 so can i make this as
ALTER TABLE userinfo  CHARSET=utf-8 COLLATE=utf-8_general_ci;

Comment: also which part of the query i should add this can i add after PRIMARY KEY (user_basic_info_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (user_id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 ALTER TABLE userinfo CHARSET=utf-8 COLLATE=utf-8_general_ci
  ); like this or this is wrong can you please tell.

Comment: no its not accepting the error is 
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xD8\xB3\xD9\x84\xD8\xA8...' for column 'city' at row 1

Comment: i want to save arabic content in mysql. if i send in english its saving but when i enter arabic its saying this error.