# My Language translation does not work in Google chrome and IE

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, translation

I developed a **web application** for the process of **Language translation from English to
Arabic.**

it is a model profile page. Its has two links in the bottom of the page if I click the
**"English"** link it will display in English and i have a **"Arabic"** link which will display in Arabic

I am able to insert the Non-English values in to the **MySQL DB** and can retrieve it back.

I downloaded and changed the **Locale Switcher plugin** in Firefox and also made changes for my 
computer input language. **Its working fine in Firefox** but it is not working in **GOOGLE CHROME**
and **IE**. its not even changing to Arabic language when i click the 'Arabic" link in bottom

What is the problem in the other browsers. What should I do to make my Web-App work in
all of the browsers.

**Edit**: My **English page** will Look Like this.
 [image]

When I click the **Arabic Link** it will change as [image]
You can see the changes in label. Now i want two things to understand
     1. I want see the same changes happening in all the browsers. what should I do?
     2. If i am sending this web app to a person who doesnot have a locale installed in his
system should be able to access both the links.
   How should i achieve this? i am clueless.

**My Server Side code for inserting into DB:**

```
            try{
        con = LanguageTranslation.getConnection();
        System.out.println("Inside try");
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO    TRANSLATE SET NAME= ?, SEX= ?, CITY= ?, COMMENTS= ?, BMONTH= ?, BDATE= ?, BYEAR= ? ");
        pstmt.setString(1, details.getName());
        pstmt.setInt(2, details.getSex());
        pstmt.setString(3, details.getCity());
        pstmt.setString(4, details.getComment());
        pstmt.setString(5, details.getMonth());
        pstmt.setString(6, details.getDate());
        pstmt.setString(7, details.getYear());
        i=pstmt.executeUpdate();
            }
            catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();            
            }
           return details;
```

**Update:**
  My **html** page corresponding to both the links(English and Arabic is)

```
       <input type="button" id="clearbutton" value="clear" onclick="clearprofile()">
       <input type="button" id="findbutton" value="find" onclick="finddetails()">
       </div> 
       <a id="EnglishLanguageLink" name="en-US" href="#"> English</a>
       &nbsp;
       <a id="ArabicLanguageLink" name="ar-SA" href="#"> Arabic</a>
```

My **JS** 
           function Intialize(){
       $('#EnglishLanguageLink').click(this.changelanguage); 
       $('#ArabicLanguageLink').click(this.changelanguage);
}

```
       this.changelanguage=function(){
       var name =   this.name;
       $(this).translate("languages/UserPortal.json", name);    
        };
```

Inside the name attribute I will pass the languages en-US and ar-SA. which will see the json file and make the corresponding changes for the language.

Comment: Well what does your "Arabic" link do? You need to give a lot more information.

Comment: @jon i will edit and update my question now. Actually if I click the Arabic Link the contents in the page Like name, class, standard will change to arabic which are displayed in the web app near text box.

Comment: Sounds like you just haven't changed the Locale in your other browsers, right?

Comment: @Leo-vin: So when you wrote "its not even changing to Arabic language when i click the 'Arabic' link in bottom" you didn't really mean it? You need to be very precise in your question.

Comment: @skeet sorry.I want to mean that except firefox when i use it in other browsers, when i click the Arabic link the transformation itself not happening,no change is there. If you see my edit of my question you can get a clear view of my problem Please.

Comment: Please show some actual (server side) code that your language switcher is using! Otherwise it's impossible to help

Comment: @noon Ya I didnt change the locale in other browsers. How to change in chrome and IE.

Comment: @pekka This code doesnot have server side code am doing it fully in client side itself.

Comment: Can you show the client side code then?

Comment: @Pekka Sorry for the translation i said no serverside coding but. for saving in database am using server side. I will edit the question with my code.

Comment: @skeet @pekka I edited and posted the question as you wanted. Please have a look.

Comment: @Leo-vin you'll probably have to debug the code, see at which point the locale change doesn't work. Alternatively, post more info about the translate plugin you are using, maybe somebody knows something about it

Comment: Your question and information is incomplete. You need to elaborate what exactly happens when you click the link in FF and Chrome/IE. What get executed and what not. What information get passed and what not.

Comment: @Balu actually in FF when i click the link arabic as shown in the screenshot the language changes.if i enter the values in arabic it saves in mysql as arabic and i can retrieve it back in Arabic,,,, whereas in Chrome/IE if i click the Arabic link the page content doesn't translate. but i can save and retrieve arabic contents in all the three. I corrected the mysql tables and DB for utf settings as you said here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245386/where-to-add-the-utf-8-extension-in-the-html-page.

Comment: This is not a DB problem. Something went wrong during processing the HTTP request which was fired by the link. So, the HTML code of the link itself and the servlet code which should process the link is of interest. It look like that some link parameter wasn't correctly definied, passed or processed. Firebug may help a lot in investigating the root cause of the issue.

Comment: @balu thank you-My confusion is, it works fine in firefox without bugs as i expect. the same things is not working in google chrome and IE.How should i move forward. Please see my update in question so that you can guide me. I will update it now.

Comment: @balu Please see the update. This will make your view clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments, it seems all you need to do is change the locale that is sent in Chrome and IE.

Infact, it's just sent in the Request headers as "Accept-Language". Worth noting W3C's [official stance](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales) on this matter, but anyway, you provide alternatives via the aforementioned link.

So, in Chrome you can change it under "Fonts and Languages". I.E. will have a similar setting (you can search for it).

But really, there is no "issue" here; test it in one browser (the checking of this header) and you've tested it in all. Interface/Design/Whatever issues aside, you don't need to test *this* in all browsers, IMHO.

I leave it with you.

Comment: Thank you very much.I am thinking in user side. If the user is using another browser which am not using and also he has not configured locale means. he might not be able to use my application right. I want a solution such that user must be able to use my application and gets translated, if he uses it in any of the browsers no matter whether he has locale setting for his browser. this is what am trying to do. Is that a wrong idea. if so guide me with your thoughts I am very eager learn and implement things in this way.

Comment: @Leo: I understand. The approach is as you've already done - provide a link to change the language. So then, you handle the language as part of the url, something like: example.org/en-AU/... Whichever you do has affects on SEO or other considerations, but basically you just need to allow a way to change it manually.