# Not showing ISO-8859-1 characters

Tags: mysql, jsp, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

MY JSP pages are not showing latin characters. América turns into Am?rica.
I've already put on top of every JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>`
```

and on top of the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

Also tried to set on the connection with the database:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database3?charSet=ISO8859-1
```

And I also configured it to ISO-8859-1 on the project's properties with no success, although my database tables are showing the Latin characters just fine.

What am I missing?

The status on my database is:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysql.exe  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.15, for Win32 (x86)
Connection id: 6
Current database:       database3
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.5.15 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             localhost via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
TCP port:               3306
Uptime:                 12 min 22 sec
Threads: 2  Questions: 102  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 50  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 27  Queries per second avg: 0.137
```

The status on my table is:

```
| Name     | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation       | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+----------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| address | InnoDB |      10 | Compact     |    4 |           4096 |       16384 |               0 |        16384 |   4194304 |              5 | 2011-09-07 18:46:49 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci |     NULL |                |         |
```

As you can see, collation is `utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: Have you included the meta tag?

Comment: @Daniel: irrelevant, that's ignored when content is served over HTTP.

Comment: Maybe the problem isn't with the database but the web container? Have you checked [Tomcat's How to use UTF-8 everywhere](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q8) -- other containers will have similar documentation/procedures. I tend to forget my `CharacterEncodingFilter` in every new project.

Comment: The above can trivially be applied to ISO-8859-1, but like BalusC said: Go UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

> ... *América turns into Am?rica* ...
>
> ... *although my database tables are showing the Latin characters just fine* ...

That the characters display just fine in your database table and that you're getting an `?` as result, indicates that your database table is *actually* storing it in a different encoding, most likely UTF-8 (which is nowadays the recommended encoding to gain [world domination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)).

Change *everything* to be UTF-8 and this problem should disappear. This article which is targeted on Java EE web developers should give a good introduction: [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: I've changed it now to UTF-8 and now América turns into Am,rica on every browser

Comment: This comma is not helpful in determining the cause of the problem (read: finding the charset it was originally encoded in). What operating system platform are you using? What's the platform's default charset? Did you check/change the MySQL DB encoding? Did you check/change the MySQL table encoding? Did you check/change the JDBC driver encoding? Did you check/change the JSP/Servlet HTTP response encoding?

Comment: yes, I've changed all of these to UTF-8. All of these were in my first message as ISO-8859-1 and then I've changed them to UTF-8. I've changed the database with the `?charSet=ISO8859-1` and I'm using Windows 7 32-bit

Comment: The JDBC driver connction URL has to be a bit different than that. Check the [Databases](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#Databases) section of the linked article.

Comment: Sorry for taking SO long but I made sure of reading all tutorials posted in here. best solution (as you pointed out in your last message) would be to add ?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8 at the end of the hibernate database connection.
it keeps giving me an error saying I should end characterEncoding with a ; delimiter. I try both ways but they both make my database connection crash

Comment: Then you were specifying it in some XML file. You need to use `&amp;` instead of `&` then. The `&` is namely a special XML character which indicates the start of a XML entity (which is to be closed by `;`).

Comment: That worked for the XML. I think the problem is really in the database. When i dropped the database and inserted the value "América" in the database, MySQL complained:
`ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\x82rica...' for column 'street' at row 1`

Comment: bc of the space for reply, I edited my original post with the status of my database. Please, take a look

Comment: Your DB supports UTF-8, but does your table? Please check the bottom half of this answer to a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245386/where-to-add-the-utf-8-extension-in-the-html-page/4245514#4245514

Comment: The collation definies the natural ordering behaviour of character-based fields (e.g. `á` becomes after `a`, not after `z`), not the character set they are stored in. I'd say, try creating a new DB/table with the `CHARACTER SET` really clearly definied by yourself, even though it's just for testing to exclude the one and other. If that doesn't fix it, I'd suspect your JDBC driver. Does its version match the DB version?

Comment: Tried creating database again with `create database bancosimples DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci`. Is it the driver? JDBC driver is ConnectorJ 5.1.17 and MySQL is 5.5.15

Comment: And the table? Driver version looks fine. What operating system platform?

Comment: table is `ALTER TABLE address CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`  and I'm using Windows 7 32-bit

Answer (score 0):

BalusC *probably* has the right answer. However, also be aware that modern browsers mis-interpret ISO-8859-1 as Windows codepage 1252 (for historic reasons) and there are small discrepancies between those two encodings. So if your data *really* is encoded in ISO-8859-1 then you’re out of luck – you *cannot* serve this encoding, you need to re-encode all your data (and then you should move to UTF-8).

Comment: This is true, but both encodings share the **same** codepoint for `é`: `U+00E9`. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Codepage_layout.

Comment: @BalusC This is why I insinuated that your answer was the right one. ;-)